# Setting memtable properties returns ConfigurationException, "Invalid yaml" due to ParserException

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-4.0

How can I update memtable size in Cassandra 4.1.2?

In `cassandra.yaml` I update value for key `memtable_heap_space: 5000` and `memtable_offheap_space: 5000` and restart cassandra service. I got Exception while restart.
[Exception Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNiZO.png) .

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! A friendly reminder that this site is for getting help with coding, algorithm, or programming language problems so I voted to have your post moved to [DBA Stack Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra). For future reference, you should post DB admin/ops questions on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra. Cheers!

Comment: Also, I'd like to make a friendly request and ask that you paste the outputs in text instead of screenshots. A lot of the engineers who answer questions here respond during their free time on their mobile devices and screenshots are very difficult to read. It would make it easier to help you if you paste the text instead. For reference, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YAML is a data serialisation language commonly used for configuration files. Similar to Python, indentation is important since it is used to determine the structure of the data, with nested data indicating hierarchy.

If you incorrectly nest (indent) the lines with either missing or extra spaces, it makes the YAML invalid and the YAML parser won't be able to read it properly.

In your case, the exception shows that the parser failed on line 616 of the `cassandra.yaml` because it was expecting the nested block to end but got a block "start" because of the extra space at the start of the line:

```
...
Caused by: org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserException: while parsing a block mapping
 ...
expected <block end>, but found '<block mapping start>'
 in 'reader', line 616, column 2:
     memtable_heap_space: 5000
     ^
 ...
```

If you remove the space ( ) at the start of the line, it should resolve the problem.

You should always check that entries in `cassandra.yaml` are formatted correctly or Cassandra will fail to start. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

The error you posted in the image indicates that the YAML file is improperly formatted.  As `memtable_heap_space` and `memtable_offheap_space` are commented out by default, it looks (to me) like you may have an extra space before each of those properties.  That's not valid for the YAML format.

In my example below, you can see that `memtable_heap_space` is formatted correctly, while `memtable_offheap_space` is not.

```
# Min unit: MiB
memtable_heap_space: 2048MiB
# Min unit: MiB
 memtable_offheap_space: 2048MiB
```

Also note that these properties are in MiB. If the desired outcome is to increase memtable usage in GiBs, you'll want to make sure those are multiples of 1024 and not 1000:

```
5000 MiB = 4.883 GiB
5120 MiB = 5.0 GiB
```